# How to update state so that the search works correctly?

Tags: reactjs

How to update state so that the search works correctly?

I try to do a search, but get the previous state state:

example:
*i write: google
console: googl*

```
const onHandleSearchResult = e => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value); 
};

<Search
    placeholder="input search text"
    onChange={onHandleSearchResult}
/>
```

Comment: Hi @reacter, do you mind including a working example?  The snippet should be able to render via Babel

Comment: it is hard to tell from your example, but setSearchValue is async function, so your console.log may output googl since it didn't update yet. try to use async await for that

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it seems that you are doing `console.log` after setting value in `state`. I believe your code looks something like below:

```
setSearchValue = (searchedValue) => {
   this.setState({ searchedValue });
   console.log('searchedValue:', this.state.searchedValue);
}
```

However, above code won't work like you mentioned in question. Reason being that [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) is async. If you want to show correct value of `state`, use callback function in `setState`. e.g.

```
setSearchValue = (searchedValue) => {
   this.setState({ searchedValue }, () => {
      console.log('searchedValue:', this.state.searchedValue);
   });
}
```

This way, `console.log` will happen only when value is set in `state`.

Comment: @reacter Did above answer helped you?